# Strange ListView selection behavior on Android

Tags: android, listview

Got an activity that extends `ListActivity`.
The list is backed up by a custom adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`.

```
getListView().setFocusable(true);
getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

I do a simple `(getSelectedItemPosition() == ListView.INVALID_POSITION)` check in `onPrepareOptionsMenu()` to disable the items that require an item to be selected.

Now, what I do after launching the activity (the action takes place
under emulator, ver.1.1) an what it looks like:

1. Hit menu - the menu items are disabled - OK
2. Select an item with mouse wheel and hit menu - the items get enabled
   -OK
3. Click anywhere outside the list, repeat 2). The items don't get
   enabled - WTF?
4. Start from scratch, select an item hitting Del and moving mouse. The
   result is the same as for 3.

Why do these (3, 4) things keep happening to me? :)
TIA.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Relying on the `selectedItemPosition` on a `ListView` can be a dangerous approach. In my experience if the List loses focus (by clicking something else) the `selectedItemPosition` gets set to `INVALID_POSITION`.

Basically if your item doesn't have that orange 'highlighted' look to it, count on the `selectedItemPosition` being null.

As an alternative you may want to remember the selected item by overriding the `onItemClick` and `onItemSelection` methods and saving the selected item's index, then use that to control your menu option availability.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the top-notch book! Loved the clear way it's written in.
As for the ListView, I _have_ the item selected/highlighted, still no (consistent) luck. Works straight after Activity start but not after smth else has been performed.
Thanks for the alternative way.